# OData concern for SQL injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, ado.net, odata

Suppose I have a DB full of health records and an ASP.NET MVC application.
Suppose someone uses the URL "/api/medicalRecords?$filter=id gt 0" to call upon an Ajax request.
This seems to me that it is open for SQL injection - just like 10-15 years ago...

Does this mean that it is by standard open to SQL injection, or does it depend on server side (I use IQueryable result and entity framework 4)?

I know that authentication mechanism is necessary - but for the sake of this question, suppose no authentication mechanism is available...

Comment: I know this is a really old question but maybe helpful for future readers, in the example you provided I'd make the ID non filterable. Instead use the usual Odata convention of `MedicalRecords(1)` to retrieve a single resource. You can configure a property as being non filterable when defining your `Edm` model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to read this blog post, which provides very detail information about OData and SQL Injection:

http://kscottmorrison.com/tag/sql-injection/

> ...OData, of course, is the data source connection, so injection isn’t an
>   issue—just getting a hold of it in the first place is enough. So what
>   is critically important with OData is to strictly manage what this
>   connection is capable of doing...

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for... and Google didn't help much :-).
Now I understand that it all depends on how I manage the connection and expose the data to the application users.

Comment: Still searching for the answer. Have not found it yet.

Answer (score 5):

WCF Data Services will parameterize the values from your filter which eliminates the possibility for SQL injection.

I'd recommend viewing the actual SQL queries executed in a database profiler.

Comment: So, let me understand - I'd have to use WCF for calling the Entity Framework data model? and what happens if I use the Enitity framework data model directly?

Comment: Is that not what you're already doing? Your question is about OData in .NET, which comes in the form of WCF Data Services.

Comment: No, it is ASP.NET MVC application, and I remove the use of WCF...
Though, even if I use WCF the if id in the criteria field is greater than 0, it's still legal for WCF...

Comment: Well, then it goes down to not being stupid and sanitize all the user side input - which is the URL in this case, for example. If you pas it through with "simple" string manipulation to the sql server you get what you asked for.